# Refrain Django from translating dates

Tags: python, django, django-i18n

I have a django app where I'm using translations.

My problem is that django is translating the dates as well, and I want to keep the dates in the same format for all languages. Is there a solution to this? It is making other problems  for me, forms are not validating dates because of this. I'm getting the date picker in english as shown in the following image, whereas I need it in French if the language is set to french.

[image]

Here are my language settings

```
USE_I18N = True          # use internationalization
USE_L10N = True          # use localization

from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


LANGUAGES =[ ('en', _('English')),
('fr', _('French')),
('ar', _('Arabic')),]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With `L10N` you can define a formats file for each language that specifies things like date formats.

The docs on this are here; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/formatting/

When creating [custom format files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/formatting/#creating-custom-format-files) you can add a setting to your project;

```
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH = [
    'mysite.formats',
    'some_app.formats',
]
```

And your formats directory would look like;

```
mysite/
    formats/
        __init__.py
        en/
            __init__.py
            formats.py
```

For examples of what you can add to these files, check out what django itself does with them [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/conf/locale/en/formats.py)

You'd just create one of these files for each of your languages and make sure that the formats are the same in each.